How to identify the source of a popup prompting user to select account on macOS?
At seemingly random times, we have a user that sees a popup window appear on their Mac prompting them to select an account.
The only account they're presented with is one labeled work.
I'm having trouble figuring out what is causing this popup to appear.
When the user selects their work account nothing appears to change other than the popup dissapearing for a few hours.
Any idea what might be causing this?


Does selecting "Choose Other…" give any clues? Like maybe it brings up the whole app that's doing this, or the longer list of choices makes the context more apparent?
